# Call Function on Enter View Controller

Tags: ios, estimote

I'm pretty new to iOS development, so I apologize if this is an easy or beginner level question.  I'm working on creating an iphone app based off of the [Estimote Indoor SDK swift example](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK/tree/master/Examples/IndoorLocation%20SwiftExample).  The main storyboard has two controllers on it: the navigation controller and a second one called the main view controller.  One this second controller there are three simple buttons, one of which is to create a floor plan layout based on a location.json file.  This button has been linked to an event to call the loadLocationFromJSON() function which is located in the MenuViewController.swift file.

Now, I can deploy the app on my phone and it builds perfectly (and works as expected).  However, I'd like to modify the app so that instead of loading the scene with the three buttons... I'd like to jump directly to calling the loadLocationFromJSON() function and displaying the floor plan on the first page that the user sees.  It would appear that I could somehow just call that function whenever that view controller is entered... but I don't know how to do that.  I tried creating a separate view controller and have the navigation controller segue to that view controller rather than the other one... but I could figure out how to call the function to load the location from the JSON file. Again, I apologize if that's a very specific question... but any help would be greatly aprpeciated.

Comment: how do you mean _entered_? appeared? loaded? touched?

Comment: I'm more used to .NET development, so I apologize if I don't understand the terms correctly... but the intent would be to automatically call the loadLocationFromJSON() function as soon as the user clicks the icon to start the app.  Instead of being confronted by the menu, it just loads the floor plan automatically.  Would that be on loaded?

Comment: it is kinda board... because you could put the procedure inside the `–viewDidLoad` method, it runs only when the instance loaded into the memory, or you could put into `–viewWillAppeared:` / `–viewDidAppeared:` methods, it would be invoked every occasion when those methods called. when are those methods' invoked? well, that may help on you to find the proper place in the lifecycle: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function inside

`-viewDidLoad`

or

`-viewWillAppear`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not good to write code that jumps to another view controller in the method "viewDidLoad". Anything related to view or initialisations related to view controller only needs to be handled in "viewDidLoad" method.

Comment: @Satyam I thought the floor layout was shown in the main view controller...  So the code would be inside of the viewDidLoad of the main view controller. Am I not right? I'm sorry if I'm not. I'm pretty new too.